# Strange .net webservice 503 issue

Tags: .net, web-services, http-status-code-503

I have a fairly strange(IMO) issue here with a webservice provided by a third party.

On calling the webservice on the live server, all works as expected. Calling it on a development setup, *sometimes* returns with a `503 - Service unavailable`, other times it works. Intermittent....
Both of these tests are done from the same client, so I don't think its a network level problem.

Now, the strange thing is, if I place a breakpoint on the line before the webservice call, and step over the call, it works. Even running the code(F5) past this breakpoint allows it to succeed. Adding a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` before the call(to simulate a breakpoint, of sorts), doesnt have any effect.

I don't have access to the remote servers, I know its server 2003/IIS 6.0 though, and the company that provides the system the webservice interfaces with, claim there's no issue with their server / software.

So before I go seriously pointing the finger, anyone experienced anything like this before, or anything else I can try?

Comment: Are the servers under heavy load? Does this ever happen with only one client?

Comment: @Oded no, no load on the dev server, live server a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this was caused by a issue on a transparent(ip spoofing) proxy, that sits upstream between my system and the remote system. The proxy was returning the 503, but under the guise of the target host.

I only managed to find this by fluke, how would I have identified this if I was to look for this type of issue, as theres nothing in the http headers /raw dump that jump out at me to point to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`503` is an error from the server. It cannot be coming from the client.

If it's necessary to "prove" this, then you would need to watch the network traffic using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) or something like it.

Comment: I wouldnt need to get to that level to prove it, I just dont want to end up with egg on my face when I start pointing the finger, because I've missed something obvious.

Comment: @jasper: you'll sound much more convincing if you understand that all HTTP error codes come from the server, and all `500` codes are _due_ to the server.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the server does not accept multiple requests in a short period from the same client in order to protect itself from DoS attacks.

In such a case, clients are required to incorporate a throttling limit to their requests. So check again with your service provider.

Comment: nothing like this unfortunately(they claim), and if there was, i'd expect the same behaviour when i run on the live system.